# Issue with Grouped TableView Text Field

Tags: iphone, tableview

I am having an issue getting my text field to return something, instead of null, with my grouped UITableView.

Here is my code:

```
#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 2;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

//adding all the UITextField's to the UITableViewCell is a pain in the ass. Pretty sure this is correct though.

if ([indexPath section] == 0) {

    nbcUser = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
    nbcUser.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    nbcUser.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    nbcPass = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
    nbcPass.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    nbcPass.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    nbcPass.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

    if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
        if ([indexPath row] == 0) {

            nbcUser.placeholder = @"user@nbcuni.com";
            nbcUser.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
            nbcUser.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
        }
        if ([indexPath row] == 1) {

            nbcPass.placeholder = @"required";
            nbcPass.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            nbcPass.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            nbcPass.secureTextEntry = YES;
        }
    }

    nbcUser.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    nbcUser.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    nbcUser.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    nbcUser.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    nbcUser.delegate = self;

    nbcPass.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    nbcPass.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    nbcPass.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    nbcPass.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    nbcPass.delegate = self;

    nbcUser.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
    nbcPass.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;

    [nbcUser setEnabled:YES];
    [nbcPass setEnabled:YES];

}
if ([indexPath section] == 0) { 
    if ([indexPath row] == 0) {

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Email";
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [cell addSubview:nbcUser];
    }

    else {

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Password";
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [cell addSubview:nbcPass];
    }
}

return cell;

}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

if (textField == self.nbcPass) {

    NSString *loginsaved = nbcUser.text;
    NSLog(@"%@", loginsaved );

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}
```

Anyone else ever run into this issue? loginsaved is returning null when I type something in that field and return the keyboard.

Comment: Do not edit your question if you've solved it. Write an answer instead and then accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

`-cellForRowAtIndexPath`: may be called multiple times for the same `cell index path` (due to cell reuse, it's well explained in the documentation).

This means you're potentially adding multiple `UITextFields` to the same cell, and this may be causing a bug.

Creating the layout of the cell in the controller is the wrong pattern to begin with, so I suggest you create a UITableViewCell subclass and do that work there. That will result in a better organized code that will help you figure out what's wrong.